# Creating custom plugin for chinese tokenization

Tags: plugins, solr, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm working towards properly integrating the stanford segmenter within SOLR for chinese tokenization.

This plugin involves loading other jar files and model files. I've got it working in a crude manner by hardcoding the complete path for the files.

I'm looking for methods to create the plugin where the paths need not be hardcoded and also to have the plugin in conformance with the SOLR plugin architecture. Please let me know if there are any recommended sites or tutorials for this.

I've added my code below :

public class ChineseTokenizerFactory extends TokenizerFactory {

```
/** Creates a new WhitespaceTokenizerFactory */
public ChineseTokenizerFactory(Map<String,String> args) {
    super(args);
    assureMatchVersion();
    if (!args.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown parameters: " + args);
    }
}

@Override
public ChineseTokenizer create(AttributeFactory factory, Reader input) {
    Reader processedStringReader = new ProcessedStringReader(input);
    return new ChineseTokenizer(luceneMatchVersion, factory, processedStringReader);
}
```

}

public class ProcessedStringReader extends java.io.Reader {

```
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 8;
//private static TextProcess m_textProcess = null;
private static final String basedir = "/home/praveen/PDS_Meetup/solr-4.9.0/custom_plugins/";
static Properties props = null;
static CRFClassifier<CoreLabel> segmenter = null;
private char[] m_inputData = null;
private int m_offset = 0;
private int m_length = 0;

public ProcessedStringReader(Reader input){
    char[] arr = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    int numChars;

    if(segmenter == null)
    {
        segmenter = new CRFClassifier<CoreLabel>(getProperties());
        segmenter.loadClassifierNoExceptions(basedir + "ctb.gz", getProperties());
    }

    try {
        while ((numChars = input.read(arr, 0, arr.length)) > 0) {
            buf.append(arr, 0, numChars);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    m_inputData = processText(buf.toString()).toCharArray();
    m_offset = 0;
    m_length = m_inputData.length;
}

@Override
public int read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
    int charNumber = 0;
    for(int i = m_offset + off;i<m_length && charNumber< len; i++){
        cbuf[charNumber] = m_inputData[i];
        m_offset ++;
        charNumber++;
    }
    if(charNumber == 0){
        return -1;
    }
    return charNumber;
}
@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    m_inputData = null;
    m_offset = 0;
    m_length = 0;
}
public String processText(String inputText)
{
    List<String> segmented = segmenter.segmentString(inputText);
    String output = "";
    if(segmented.size() > 0)
    {
        output = segmented.get(0);
        for(int i=1;i<segmented.size();i++)
        {
            output = output + " " +segmented.get(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(output);
    return output;
}
static Properties getProperties()
{
    if (props == null) {
        props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("sighanCorporaDict", basedir);
        // props.setProperty("NormalizationTable", "data/norm.simp.utf8");
        // props.setProperty("normTableEncoding", "UTF-8");
        // below is needed because CTBSegDocumentIteratorFactory accesses it
        props.setProperty("serDictionary",basedir+"dict-chris6.ser.gz");
        props.setProperty("inputEncoding", "UTF-8");
        props.setProperty("sighanPostProcessing", "true");
    }
    return props;
}
```

}

public final class ChineseTokenizer extends CharTokenizer {

```
public ChineseTokenizer(Version matchVersion, Reader in) {
    super(matchVersion, in);
}
public ChineseTokenizer(Version matchVersion, AttributeFactory factory, Reader in) {
    super(matchVersion, factory, in);
}

/** Collects only characters which do not satisfy
 * {@link Character#isWhitespace(int)}.*/
@Override
protected boolean isTokenChar(int c) {
    return !Character.isWhitespace(c);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the argument through the Factory's args parameter.